# pyparsing parsing csv files with semi-colon instead of comma

Tags: python, csv, pyparsing

In mainland europe, the csv files are separated through semicolons because numbers have , in them instead of . So, i am trying to write a semicolonSeparatedList same as commaSeparatedList but with ; instead of ,:

```
_semicolonsepitem = Combine(OneOrMore(Word(printables, excludeChars=';') +
                             Optional( Word(" \t") +
                                       ~Literal(";") + ~LineEnd() ) ) ).streamline().setName("semicolonItem")
semicolonSeparatedList = delimitedList( Optional( quotedString.copy() | _semicolonsepitem, default="") ).setName("semicolonSeparatedList")
```

However parsing:

```
Name;Ref;Address
```

results in

```
['Name']
```

instead of

```
['Name', 'Ref', 'Address']
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Glad you were able to resolve this for yourself - I hope pyparsing finds a place in your Python toolkit.

Answer (score 11):

Have you tried the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) from python?

There, you can specify the delimiter easily.

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
```

Edit after Birei's comment : I just took example from docs python page, you can input anything you want as a delimiter for csv reader :
 
' '
','
';'
'a'

Comment: I suppose a typo in `delimiter`. It's a semicolon.

Comment: The csv module has a problem I couldn't resolve. It doesn't work with both "" and '' values as quotechars, and users tend to do things like O'Neill or "secon'time" or 'tag1' and it needs to work with all. That's why I chose pyparser as it works with all.