# Is there any way to read arrays in text file, but the elements in array are separated by semicolons?

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I would like to read the array elements and assign them to the new array called `data_array`, but elements in the array in the text file are separated by semicolons. How should I do if I want to read them normally as they are separated by commas? Furthermore, I want to read the line one by one.

Contents of file `data.txt` is as follows:

```
4; -9; -1; 9; -1; -3; 8; 8; 0; -9; -8 
7; 6; 5; -6; 5; -4; 2; 1; -1; -6; 0; 3; -7; 9; 9; 6; -5; -8; 1; -8; -1; -1
-8; -6; -6; -5; -6; -8; -4; -2; 8; -3; 3; 6; 4; -9; 10; 2; -4; 7; -5; 0; -3; 7; -7; 6; -10; 8; -9; 9; 2; -1; -6; 6; -5; 8; 0; 3; 6; -10; -2; 8; -6; -5; 9; 10
1; 7; -6; 7; 6; 2; 9; 2; 3; 1; 0; 8; 5; 2; 4; 9; -10; 3; -9; 9; -2; 8; -1; 4; -4; -3; -10; -2; -9; -5; 7; 9; -4; 6; 10; -1; -8; 10; -2; 2; -9; 2; -2; 2; 3; 10; 6; 3; -3; -5; -4; 6; -4; -2; 2; -5; 4; -8; 0; -2; -5; -4; 3; 4; -6; -10; 3; -5; -10; -3; 4; 10; 10; 5; -5; 0; 10; 2; 9; 7; -8; -2; 10; 4; 10; 9; 3; -7; 
-3; -9; 5; -10; -3; 3; -7; 8; 8; 1; 8; -10; 0; -6; -10; 3; -10; 1; -1; -2; 10; 3; -3; -10; 9; -3; 9; 6; 2; 3; 6; -10; 1; -4; -1; 8; 5; 7; -6; -9; 1; -6; -9; 8; -7; -5; -4; -1; 10; 8; -10; -3; -10; -5; 1; 0; 5; -6; 7; 3; -8; -9; -8; -6; 3; 4; 0; 5; -9; 8; 7; -2; 0; -7; 7; 1; -2; 10; -7; 3; 10; -10; 5; 3; 3; -7; -3; -6; -3; -4; -6; 4; -1; 10; 7; 1; 5; 6; 0; -8; -6; -5; 6; 9; 2; 2; -8; 3; 2; -8; 1; -2; -10; 3; 8; 3; 6; 2; -5; 6; -8; -6; 10; -1; -7; 9; 3; -8; -9; 3; -2; 2; -9; -6; -2; -9; -4; 7; -6; 3; -5; 5; 4; 6; -7; 0; -4; 8; -9; 3; -1; -7; -9; 1; -5; -3; -2; 0; 4; 4; -3; -5; -8; -3; 0; -1; 5; -9; 5; 2; 4; 3; 3; 4; 10; -2
```

Here's my attempt:

```
f = open("data.txt", "r")
data_array = [f.readline()]

array_length = len(data_array)
```

The output is not what I expected, says the length of the array is only one.

Is there any way that I can improve this much better?

Comment: you could maybe use [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module from the stdlib

Comment: `a=splitlines()` to split by lines. `for line in a` to loop line by line and `line.split(';')` to split by this delimiter. The same as in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922214/reading-a-text-file-and-splitting-it-into-single-words-in-python/16922328

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pyparsing parsing csv files with semi-colon instead of comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514602/pyparsing-parsing-csv-files-with-semi-colon-instead-of-comma)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it

```
import csv
result = []
with open('test.txt', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in spamreader:
        result += [int(x) for x in row]
```

and result

```
[4, -9, -1, 9, -1, -3, 8, 8, 0, -9, -8, 7, 6, 5, -6, 5, -4, 2, 1, -1, -6, 0, 3, -7, 9, 9, 6, -5, -8, 1, -8, -1, -1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for-loop:

```
f = open("data.txt", "r")
data_array = list()
for line in f.read():
    data_array.append(line.split(";"))
```

Then, it's possible to convert them to ints using a list comprehension:

```
for line in f.read():
    data_array.append(int(num) for num in line.split(";"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) reads the numeric values from the file and converts them to [ints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).

Calling [str.splitlines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) on the contents of the file produces output that's easier to work with than simply looping over the file.

[filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)(None, line.split(';')) gives us the result of [line.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)(';') with empty strings removed.

```
data_array = [int(n) for line in f.read().splitlines()
              for n in filter(None, line.split(';'))]
```

It's the equivalent of this code:

```
data_array = []
for line in f.read().splitlines():
    for n in line.split(';'):
        n = n.strip()
        if n:
            data_array.append(int(n))
```